# Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT when loading a flask page

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask

I am getting `AW Snap Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT` when loading a flask page. I am loading plotly charts and some pics. Particular page is throwing this error. It was working fine but suddenly throwing this error.

What could be reason for this error. I could not debug this error. PLease help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your **status_breakpoint** error may result from an outdated web browser version. Old browser versions often have many issues, which the newer versions fix. Also, keep all your installed apps updated, including web browsers.

You can **resolve your error by updating your Chrome or Edge browser to the latest version**.